# Remote desktop connection drops before login can appear

Tags: windows-xp, rdp

I have a client with Remote Desktop enabled that I can't connect to in our local network. When I enter in the machine ip/port in the connect box and hit Connect, it briefly gives the normal "Connecting..." dialog box.

However, after 2 seconds it just drops. No error message, nothing. Just disappears as if nothing was happening.

- Windows XP SP3
- RDP port changed to 31444 (changed from 32325 when that didn't work)
- Windows firewall is open for 31444 TCP
- Machine is on a domain
- RDP is enabled in My Computer
- User is a local admin

I have loads of other machines on the same domain with the same GPO that work fine.

Any ideas?

jpe

Comment: In Computer MAnagement -> Local Users & Groups -> Groups, is the user part of the "Remote Desktop Users" group?

Comment: Are there any messages in the event logs related to RDP (both client and server)?

Comment: @gharper - They are local admins.
@squillman - Don't think so, but I'll check Tuesday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has happened to me in the past on a couple different servers.  At the time, the problem ended up being with the video card driver on the server.  Removing the old driver and updating to the latest fixed the problem for me.  If there is no newer version, you could also try using a previous version.

Comment: @Ryan: Any chance that it was an nvidia card?

Comment: I don't honestly remember.  But it would've been a Dell server and I think I remember them running ATI cards...perhaps something like Radeon 7000.  I can easily see it happening to any vendor's card though depending on the quality of the driver.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue.  I ended up using the Computer Management console and changing to that computer to get to the event log.  Once in the event log I found a cryptic message that I was able to figure out the solution to the Remote Desktop not connecting.